# Time series: Deterministic trend?

Tags: r, time-series, trend

I am setting a VAR model with two variables. One of the variables looks like this:

[image: timeseries]

Do you think it's still appropriate to setup the VAR as a time series with "drift" or do you think it must be "drift and trend"? The data is already log-transformed.

I read a few papers and my impression is that every author is handling it differently. The "trend" graph shows that there is a trend but when looking at the graph, it does not seem very clear.

Comment: Whether it is drift or "trend", you want to supply (V)AR model with stationary or pseudo-stationary data. What if you take: a) first differences, b) first log differences of your vector and try to investigate the existence of: a) autoregressive part, b) seasonality?

Comment: The data is log-level and ADF indicates stationarity at 5% level when accounting for a "drift" trend.

Comment: Are data log scale, or differences are on log scale?

Comment: Data is log scale, not differenced

Comment: OK. If you want to make forecast using your decomposition, you are about to know how to forecast all the components. I assume you can model trend as a linear function of time. You can model seasonality as either autoregressive model or seasonal difference model. Besides you can model residuals by taking AR component of them. Does it make sense?

Comment: If you make a different choice and instead of seasonal decomposition you just take first differences OR first log differences, then you still everything you need to go on with modeling. You still keep seasonality component, and a trend component (mean difference will be > 0).

Comment: You are welcome. If you liked it, please mark one of my comments as the answer.

Comment: It looks like I can't?

Comment: Ok then )) if you need more guidance feel free to add comments here.